# Flash stage full screen mode, movieclip full screen mode?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am wondering from this code, it makes the stage full screen, does it also makes the content of my movieclips scaled to full screen? i have tried this code and it does not seem to do that, how can i make my content to scale to fill a stage's full screen? i have a Movieclip containing a background with a class to make special effects on the background, i am having trouble making the background be "fullscreened" nicely with the stage.

`stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

Answer (score 0):

if you setup your swf using `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, you should use a RESIZE eventlistener on the stage to achieve the resizing of the content:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);

private function onStageResize(event:Event):void
{
  // resize your content with the new stage proprotions
  myContent.setSize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
```

Comment: i heard that flash do not .swfs to be start up on fullscreen, therefore putting stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; on my contructor would not work is that right? however i did that and when i open my deployable .swf it starts up in full screen, why is that so?

Comment: The restriction is only for SWFs deployed in a browser.